# Method reference keeps object alive in Swift

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

I have noticed that some reference to object method creates strong reference to that object and keeps it alive in Swift.

Is there any way around that? Is it possible to mark method reference as weak?

```
class Counter
{
    var n: Int = 0

    func inc() -> Int
    {
        n += 1
        return n
    }
}

var o: Counter? = Counter()
weak var w: Counter? = o
var c: () -> (Int) = o!.inc

c() // 1
w?.n

o = nil

c() // 2 - object is still alive here
w?.n // weak reference is also alive here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?
I noticed the metal sample app had a weak reference in a closure.

```
class Counter
{
    var n: Int = 0

    func inc() 
    {
        n += 1
        print("new count \(n)")
    }

    deinit { 
        print("deinit")
    }
}

var counter: Counter? = Counter()

var closure: () -> ()  = {
    [weak counter] in
        if let strongRef = counter {
            print("alive")
            strongRef.inc()
        } else {
            print("dead")
        }
}

closure()
counter = nil
closure()
```

this prints

```
alive
new count 1
deinit
dead
```

Comment: Yes, that is pretty close to what I want to achieve.

Comment: I'm afraid the OP will draw the wrong conclusion here. If you remove the `[weak counter] in` from this answer, you get the exact same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`var c` is not a reference to a method, it is a reference to a [*closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) -  a package of method and whatever objects it needs on which to operate. In your case, the method `inc` needs its `Counter` object to complete its job, so `Counter` is kept alive.

Closures keeping their objects alive is a fundamental feature. The only way to let the object go is to let go of all references to its instance methods explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a closure reference `weak` but you can make it optional.

```
class Counter
{
    var n: Int = 0

    func inc() -> Int
    {
        n += 1
        return n
    }
}

var o: Counter? = Counter()
weak var w: Counter? = o
var c: (() -> (Int))? = o?.inc //this is the crucial part

c?() // 1
w?.n

o = nil
c = nil

c?() //nil
w?.n //nil
```

Comment: Thanks, but that means I have to set `c` to `nil`, too. I guess there is no way around that.